# Pushing data into Array: Always get last index using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create my table dynamically by allocating it. `nbrBoules` is the variable:

```
boules:Boule :[]
boule:Boule;  Boule{id,poids}
Method(){

for (var _i = 0; _i < this.nbrBoules; _i++) {
      this.boule.id = _i;
      alert(_i);
      this.boule.poids = 10;
      this.boules[_i] = this.boule;

}
```

When I show the result of `this.boules` I always get `7-10|7-10|7-10|7-10|7-10|7-10|7-10|7-10|` and in my alert I get `0 - -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7`.

How does it work in Typescript and why do I always get the last index?

Comment: emptying your boule in the end of loop. `this.boule = {};` should work. @norbertk answer explains why you're getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but you are not creating new objects. `this.boule` doesn't change. You just set `this.boules[I]` to the same object. After running the loop the last id will be 7. But all elements of `this.boules` will point to the same object, so all of them will be 7.